# WP plugin integretion testing - how to enable additional plugins?

Tags: wordpress, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm setting up a pipeline to automate testing and releasing my WP plugin to my private Gitlab project package registry.

Followed WP [Plugin Integration Tests guide](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/misc/plugin-unit-tests/) and set up a pipeline that uses WP docker image and mysql service for the db, so far so good.

The problem is that my plugin now needs to call ACF pro `get_field()` function, so I need to install and activate it programmatically in my pipeline testing job, otherwise some tests fails with the `Error: Call to undefined function get_field()` error.

Found some articles on plugin tdd, but the most doesn't handle the 3rd party plugins requirement and the rest is based on writer's custom plugin functionalities (so I'd avoid them).

Is there some official wp tool to install/activate plugins programmatically?
Or at least some bash script/commands that I can run in the pipeline job to setup the environment?

Comment: you can try this https://gist.github.com/squarestar/37fe1ff964adaddc0697dd03155cf0d0